# How do I know what sort of List is returned?

Tags: java, hibernate, list

Using Hibernate Criteria, and have declared:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria  =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(SomeEntity.class);

List<SomeObject> myListOfObjects = detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```

How do i know what sort of list implementation is myListOfObjects?  ArrayList, LinkList etc etc..   The reason I ask this is because I traced through all the code, and according to the official documentation,

```
DetachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list()
```

returns a Criteria, and list() applied to a Criteria returns a List:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

Comment: And if you read carefully, it also says that list() returns `The list of matched query results`, that is, `SomeEntity.Class`, filtered with your criterion matching your `SomeEntity` properties you filtered the result for.

Comment: Why does it matter what type of `List` is returned? If you need a specific type it'll be safer to manually convert it into that type, otherwise you can work with the methods that are defined by the `List` interface knowing that the underlying type implements them.

Comment: Evan Knowles --  I thought that ultimately, the programmer is required to know whether there's a concrete List implementation;  otherwise, I thought you can't call any method on a List interface.  That's why I was doing the tracing, but am I correct that it's somehow hidden from me and that I assume it has a concrete list class, therefore i can use methods of the List interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can insect the runtime class of the returned List interface by using :-

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria  =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(SomeEntity.class);

List<SomeObject> myListOfObjects = detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();

System.out.println(myListOfObjects.getClass());
```

Comment: Yes, you could, but what is that good for? List provides everything one needs and apart from that, one should never rely on the concrete implementation of an interface.

Comment: @correct...I agree.In some rare case,one may try to add or delete objects..So knowing the List type will help in visualizing the performance

Answer (score 0):

You can use your **myListOfObjects** in any implementation of **List** you want. You could type cast it, use as a parameter to a constructor of a implementation of **List** and use it in utilities classes such as **Collections**.